# Replace values of multiple columns from one dataframe using another dataframe with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have two data frames as followed:

```
df1: 
ID   x    y     z     
1    a    b     c     
2    a    b     c
3    a    b     c 
4    a    b     c
```

and df2:

```
ID   x    y     
 2   d    NA
 3   NA   e
```

and I am after a result like this:

df1:

```
    ID   x    y     z     
    1    a    b     c     
    2    d    b     c
    3    a    e     c 
    4    a    b     c
```

I have been trying to use the match function as suggested by some other posts but I keep getting the issue where my df1 dataframe being replaced with NA values from df2.
This is the code I have been using without luck

```
for (i in names(df2)[2:length(names(df2))]) {
  df1[i] <- df2[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an [update join](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/183), which doesn't exist yet in dplyr, though you can get the effect by cleaning up after a normal join: `df2 %>% full_join(df1, by = 'ID', suffix = c('', '.1')) %>% mutate(x = coalesce(x, x.1), y = coalesce(y, y.1)) %>% select(-x.1, -y.1) %>% arrange(ID)`. You could do the same in base R, if you like: `df3 <- merge(df2, df1, by = 'ID', all = TRUE, suffixes = c('', '.1')); df3$x[is.na(df3$x)] <- df3$x.1[is.na(df3$x)]; df3$y[is.na(df3$y)] <- df3$y.1[is.na(df3$y)]; df3[c('x.1', 'y.1')] <- NULL; df3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't work for me so I change it a little but it works. If you are reading data from an external file use the `stringAsFactor = FALSE` when you read it so you don't run into problems.

```
df1 = data.frame("ID" = 1:4,"x" = rep("a",4), "y" =rep("b",4),"z" = rep("c",4),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 = data.frame("ID" = 2:3,"x" = c("d",NA), "y" = c(NA,"e"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  new_data = df2[i,-which(apply(df2[i,],2,is.na))]
  pos = as.numeric(new_data[1])
  col_replace = intersect(colnames(new_data),colnames(df1))
  df1[pos,col_replace] = new_data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrade, unfortunately, your code would work only if my ID column is in a nice sequential order like that. In reality, my data is more like this: ID = 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400 for df1 and 3200, 3300 for df2.

Comment: @southwind just change the `pos` with something like `which(new_data[1] == df1$ID)` and that way you will get the position in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. The code works much better than what I was trying to do: df1 [df1$ID == pos, col_replace]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`. The idea is to convert both data frames to long format, conduct join and replace the values, and convert the format back to wide format. `df5` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% gather(Col, Value, -ID) 
df4 <- df2 %>% gather(Col, Value, -ID, na.rm = TRUE)
df5 <- df3 %>%
  left_join(df4, by = c("ID", "Col")) %>%
  mutate(Value.x = ifelse(!is.na(Value.y), Value.y, Value.x)) %>%
  select(ID, Col, Value.x) %>%
  spread(Col, Value.x)
df5
#   ID x y z
# 1  1 a b c
# 2  2 d b c
# 3  3 a e c
# 4  4 a b c
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID   x    y     z     
1    a    b     c     
                  2    a    b     c
                  3    a    b     c 
                  4    a    b     c",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID   x    y     
 2   d    NA
 3   NA   e",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by alistaire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706240/replace-values-of-multiple-columns-from-one-dataframe-using-another-dataframe-wi#comment82373026_47706240) this is an *update join*. It is available with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, on = "ID", x := ifelse(is.na(i.x), x, i.x)]
df1[df2, on = "ID", y := ifelse(is.na(i.y), y, i.y)]
df1
```

> ```
>    ID x y z
> 1:  1 a b c
> 2:  2 d b c
> 3:  3 a e c
> 4:  4 a b c
> ```

---

If there are many columns with replacement values, it might be worthwhile to follow [www's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708617/3817004) to do the replacement after reshaping to long format where column names are treated as data:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), "ID")[
  melt(setDT(df2), "ID", na.rm = TRUE), on = .(ID, variable), value := i.value][
    , dcast(.SD, ID ~ variable)]
```

> ```
>    ID x y z
> 1:  1 a b c
> 2:  2 d b c
> 3:  3 a e c
> 4:  4 a b c
> ```

#### Data

```
df1 <- fread(
"ID   x    y     z     
1    a    b     c     
2    a    b     c
3    a    b     c 
4    a    b     c")

df2 <- fread(
"ID   x    y     
 2   d    NA
 3   NA   e")
```